# Is std::string str(array.begin(), array.end()) adding the null character on its own?

Tags: c++, string

I am very new to C++ and i was wondering if `std::string str(array.begin(), array.end())` is adding a null character on its own at the end of the string? I looked up this [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) but i could not figure it out. I appreciate your answers!

Edit:
I am using C++11 and I have an `boost::array<u_int8_t>` of uknown size. My goal ist to print it afterwards with `str.c_str()` because `%s` is expecting a `char*`.

```
str = std::string(arr.begin(),arr.end());
ROS_INFO("Got response: \n %s", str.c_str());
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since C++11 `std::string` must contain a terminating null character. However, a null character in a `std::string` does not necessarily terminate the `std::string`.

I hope it gets more clear with the following example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string x{"Hello World"};

    std::cout << x.c_str() << "\n";

    x[5] = '\0';
    std::cout << x << "\n";
    std::cout << x.c_str();
}
```

[prints:](https://godbolt.org/z/sacY964vh)

```
Hello World
HelloWorld
Hello
```

We can get a null-terminated c-string via `c_str` to get the expected output. The `<<` overload knows where to stop because there is a null-terminator. Though after adding a `\0` in the middle of the `std::string` we can still print the whole string with the `<<` overload for `std::string`.
Calling `c_str` again, will again return a pointer to a c-string with 10 characters + the terminating `\0`, but this time the `<<` overload for `char*` stops when it encounters the first `\0`, because thats what indicates the end of a c-string.

TL;DR: Unless you need to get a c-string from the `std::string` you need not worry about adding the null-terminator. `std::string` does that for you. On the other hand you should be aware that `std::string` can contain null characters also in the middle not only at their end.

Comment: not sure how relevant this is now after the edit for the actual question (or if it ever was). I tripped over a `\0` in the middle of a `std::string` at least once and had a fun debugging session, so I thought it is worth mentioning

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer :-)! Your  example is very good and makes the topic easier to understand.

Answer (score 7):

The C++ standard specifies that `c_str()` returns a null-terminated string (the contents of the string followed by a `'\0'`). Depending on C++ standard version, you may or may not be guaranteed that `str[str.size()]` also gives you a `'\0'`.

That's the only thing that the C++ standard specifies. Whether the `'\0'` is originally added by its constructor, or not, including this specific constructor: this is unspecified.

However, since you are guaranteed to get that all-important `'\0'` when you go look for it, this is a moot point. It will be there.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I did not know that the null character is optional for std::strings in C++. Since I programmed in C before, I thought it would behave the same here. I should be more careful with such assumptions.

Answer (score 3):

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string

> null-terminated (since C++11)CharT[] array.

C++11 standard and later guarantee null-termination.

Also here:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str

> c_str() and data() perform the same function.
> (since C++11)

As the return value of `c_str`, being a C-style string has to be null-terminated. In earlier standards, if you wanted null-termination, you would have to call `c_str()` on the string at least once to be sure.

Comment: not entierly sure, but I believe your quote is inaccurate because it lost its context. The full quote is " a pointer to s[0] can be passed to functions that expect a pointer to the first element of a null-terminated (since C++11)CharT[] array. "

Comment: I take back half of what I wrote, I was wrong and this answer explains why. Though I still think adding the complete quote would be better

Comment: There's no guarantee in the Standard that `&s[0]` points to a null-terminated string; I believe whoever wrote otherwise in the cppreference page is mistaken